# How can you answer a client with his/her name in Dialogflow when it's provided by an external service?

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a Dialogflow agent in which the client identifies with a clientId. This uses Twilio for Whatsapp chatbot integration.

```
DIALOG

 - Hi, tell me your clientId
 - abcde1234
```

At this point I need to get the client name from an external service...

```
GET Authentication: Basic xxx:yyy http://xxx/clients/id/abcde1234

-> {"id":"abcde1234", "name": "John", ...}
```

... and answer with it:

```
DIALOG

 - Hi, John, how can I help you?
```

Is this possible with Dialogflow?

Comment: Are you using a webhook? If so this should be a trivial task since you can use something like a template string,and set that as the response for your function.

Comment: Just with Dialogflow, this won't be possible due to the dependency on the third party integration

Comment: I'm actually using Dialogflow + Twilio for a Whatsapp integration

Comment: Hmm I haven't worked with Twilio and Whatsapp directly, usually we have our webhook acting as an intermediary (which is just a NodeJS express app or flask app ) and we call the twilio API from there

Comment: Once you have a webhook API running somewhere, this should be a trivial task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to fetch the value of the user's input, we can create something called a session parameter. Basically, this will be a JSON object in the API request sent to your webhook API which will present throughout the lifespan of your conversation (due to the high lifetime set for the same). You can read more in depth about contexts [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-overview).

[image: Snippet of Context variable called global-parameters]

We can then set up a simple NodeJS codebase on a Cloud Function (used this only due to its simplicity of deployment, though you are free to use any cloud provider/platform of your choice).
I made some minor modifications to the boiler plate codebase present in every Dialogflow ES agent.
[image]

So for example, here's the  changes made in the index.js file

```
.
.
.
  function welcome(agent) {
    const globalParameters = agent.getContext('global-parameters');
    const questionNumber = globalParameters.parameters.number;
    const sampleNameFromGetCall = 'John'
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent! ${sampleNameFromGetCall}`);
  }
```

and here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowfirebasefulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "dialogflow": "^1.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

Here's the library we used which is the library built by Google for this purpose.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow
Once I enabled the webhook fulfillment on my agent, I quickly tested it and

[image]

There's a major caveat to using this as this repo has been archived by Google and doesn't receive any updates, so you may have to figure out how to parse the incoming request in your webhook API OR you can use this library with some major changes to its codebase.
You would need to make sure the overall latency of your request isn't too much, [image: as Dialogflow ES has a 10 second time out for all responses.]

So, in a nutshell, yes,  we can definitely fetch a value from your Dialogflow Agent, use it to a call an API, parse that response and use that as a part of our dynamic response. The value would be stored in a JSON object called context, which will be a part of any incoming request to your webhook API.

Comment: I want to add that your clientID would not be something as simple as sys.number, I might suggest using a regex entity or sys.any (if no other thing works)

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you for taking the time to explain it so thoroughly.